# jQuery.load(), mixed HTTP/HTTPS and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, https

I'm attempting to load in a remote HTML page using `jQuery.load('https://someurl.com .someClass')`. The page doing the load is on HTTPS; the remote page is available as both HTTP and HTTPS. Everything works fine in reasonable browsers, but IE is throwing up a mixed HTTP/HTTPS content security warning -- the remote page has CSS and JS included by HTTP links, even when requested as HTTPS. Any clues as how to successfully pull in a mixed-content file in IE without it triggering the warning? Modifying the remote page isn't an option.

**EDIT**

To be clear, I'm attempting to load the remote file over HTTPS. The file contains links to HTTP resources (img, css, js); because I'm providing a selector to `.load()`, reasonable browsers don't try to parse & execute the document; IE does.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to circumvent the warning. You may have to rewrite the inlying URLs....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get around the mixed-content warning in IE.  If the remote resource is available via both HTTP and HTTPS you can make sure your protocols match `jQuery.load(location.protocol + '//someurl.com .someClass')`

---

Updated based on the problem being mixed-content in the remote page:

`jQuery.load` loads the **entire responseText** into a documentFragment before pulling out the appropriate part indicated by the selector (see [jQuery 1.4.4 ajax.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L70)).  The entire remote page is parsed as HTML and must go through the browser's security processes; in many ways it's simpler to make sure the response is "clean" by making sure all the protocols match and/or only returning a fragment if that's all you need.

If you won't be modifying the other resource, which would be *much more robust*, you'll need to replace all occurrences of HTTP with HTTPS (or vice versa) while the remote resource is still just a string.  Here's a fragile jQuery plugin as an example of this technique, mostly ripped from [jQuery 1.4.4 $.load function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L70):

```
(function($){
    var http = "http:",
        https = "https:",
        rscript = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi,
        proto = location.protocol,
        otherProtoUri = new RegExp("\\b" + (proto === http ? https : http) + "(//[a-z\\d.-]+)", "gi");

    $.fn.protocolModifyLoad = function(url, yesIKnowThisIsFragile, selector) {
        var self = this;

        if ( !this.length || !yesIKnowThisIsFragile) {
            return this;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            complete: function( res, status ) {
                // If successful, inject the HTML into all the matched elements
                if ( status === "success" || status === "notmodified" ) {
                    // Force occurences of the other protocol into the current one
                    var response = res.responseText.replace(otherProtoUri, proto + "$1");

                    // See if a selector was specified
                    self.html( selector ?
                        // Create a dummy div to hold the results
                        jQuery("<div>")
                            // inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
                            // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
                            .append(response.replace(rscript, ""))

                            // Locate the specified elements
                            .find(selector) :

                        // If not, just inject the full result
                        response);
                }
            }
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage: `$('#your > .selector').protocolModifyLoad(location.protocol + '//someurl.com', 'thisIsFragile!!!', '.someClass');`

This function omits the `callback` and `params` arguments of `$.load` and the `yesIKnowThisIsFragile` argument was added as a subtle reminder.

Comment: If you want to ensure a resource is loaded from the same protocol, then you can specify "//domain.com/path/to/resource.js" as the path, e.g. `<script src="//domain.com/path/to/resource.js"></script>`. If you are on https, then the browser will try to pull that resource from `https://domain.com`.

Comment: The resource is available as both HTTP & HTTPS and I'm loading it via HTTPS. Even though I've provided a selector to .load(), which should prevent the browser from actually parsing the document and loading & executing linked JS & CSS, IE seems to at least be parsing it and seeing HTTP links.

Comment: Protocol relative URLs (`"//example.com/example.js"`) cause IE7 and IE8 to download the file twice: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/

Answer (score 0):

If a secure page loads any nonsecure resource, its going to throw the warning.  The only way to get around it is to load everything from https.

Even the other browsers should have a warning being displayed somewhere (possibly to the left of the address in FF?)

Comment: Safari, Chrome and Firefox all work normally and do not throw an error because of the selector added to the URL -- they don't attempt to parse the whole file.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the only reason they don't throw an error is because their default nature is not to throw up a confirmation box, whereas IE's is.  I think most browsers that are not IE just warn you another way.  FF3 shows a padlock with an exclamation mark in the bottom right.  If it *were* to throw a confirmation like IE, then you'd more than likely be having the same issue in FF3.

Comment: Sorry, there's just no visible indication in a non-IE browser that anything is out of the ordinary.