# Mixed Content Warning in IE8 With JQuery UI Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, modal-dialog

I'm using JQueryUI's Dialog as a Modal window, and loading another page into the modal window using the method outlined here: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/08/07/creating-dialogs-on-demand/

The modal window is generated (see my code below), and it works great in Firefox, but in IE8, I get the dreaded mixed content warning (the site is being served up via HTTPS, and all my checks in Firebug show that everything has relative paths and is all coming from the same site as the page generating the modal. What's even more frustrating is with the mixed content warning, you're supposed to be able to answer 'no' to the prompt IE gives you, and then it should load the mixed content - but all I get is a blank modal window. It also strangely does not turn the overlay area transparent, even though non-generated modals (the modal contents are in a hidden DIV on the same page) on the same site work just fine in IE and create the modal with the transparent overlay.

I'm using JQuery 1.4.2 with JQueryUI 1.8.2, and below is my modal window code along with the code that gets the content based on the a href clicked.

```
$('.actionlink').each(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
    var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
        $dialog
        .load($link.attr('href') + ' #modalWrapper')
        .dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            //autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Printable Action Items',
            width: 700,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    $link.click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');

        return false;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here's the href that provides the page to insert into the modal window:

```
<a href="https://#cgi.server_name#/matters/viewprintableactions.cfm?matterid=#matterid#&asserter=#urlencodedformat(asserter)#" class="actionlink"><img src="/images/page_alert.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>
```

The reason for doing it this way is there can potentially be multiple links like this on the page, and I need to provide a modal for every one, but do a separate query to get the information for the modal (hence why it's in another page). We also cannot change the user's browser settings to allow for the mixed content and avoid this (I wish).

Anyone with advice or can see what the issue is here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that every reference in your **whole** generated document is relative/https? Not just the part in your `#modalWrapper` element, but the whole thing. As it is investigated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404715/jquery-load-mixed-http-https-and-internet-explorer), the `load()` function loads the whole page returned via ajax into a documentFragment before applying the selector, meaning the whole document must go through the browser's security processing.

Comment: @ DarthJDG: Nothing that I have been able to find via Firebug has indicated mixed content - I have read in past where people using JQueryUI had elements in the JQueryUI style sheet loading via http://, but in mine, all the elements are relative. What complicates this more is ColdFusion loads items into the page (a header, footer, etc. are included, but all those too are coming in as relative https). I can try isolating the page being loaded in a folder so only the content on the page loads without the included items and see if that helps.

Comment: Update: I managed to get the mixed content warning to go away - I moved the file I was calling into a separate folder with it's own application.cfm file so it wouldn't pull any of the auto-inlcuded files in (just to rule out any potential items). It still for some inexplicable reason does not turn the modal window overlay opaque, even though other modal windows on the site (although not called in the same way) show it as semi-transparent. I'm giving you the credit Darth since you semi-led me down the path I eventually took!

Comment: Are you experiencing the overlay problem in a certain browser or all of them? I also found an active bug report, although I doubt that your page has a height over 65536px. :) http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6801

Comment: Oddly enough, in IE6 of all browsers, I get the transparent overlay (as well in Firefox). This only affects IE8, and actually regarding the page height - I have ColdFusion debugging on, and when I was testing a print page feature, I forgot to turn off the debugging and the print output was going to be 72 pages (!) - I am sure that would exceed that. I just need to see if turning off debugging would solve that, but that doesn't explain why Firefox doesn't experience it (unless that bug report you found was specific to IE), and I need to verify if IE6 is showing the debug output.