# issue in when loading html file within html using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, safari

I loaded a complete html(see below for skeleton) page with the following structure into the another html page using clicking of the button.

```
    <!--START:HTML to be loaded by ajax-->
<head>
<!--START: The content inside this head tag is not processed while the page is loaded via ajax-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/rrr.css" media="screen, projection, print" />
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="aaas/xxxx.js"></script>
<!--END: The content inside this head tag is not processed while the page is loaded via ajax-->
</head>

<div id="content">
    <!--Page content on which the above script tags inside head tag to act-->
</div>
<!--END:HTML to be loaded by ajax-->
```

In safari version 5.0.1 and in 5.0.2, the content inside the head tag is not parsed, but the content inside html is parsed in all IE,FF and chrome and safari 5.1.2.
and Content inside div with id equal to "content" is shown in all browsers including safari 5.0.1 and 5.0.2.
Please help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: the script inside the head tag is processed, when i remove the head tag alone and make the script tags as sibling of div with id "content"

Answer (score 0):

The LINK element can only be used in the HEAD of a document.

From [the reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) :

> Unlike A, it may only appear in the HEAD section of a document,
>   although it may appear any number of times.

So you may load this inside a `iframe` (which holds a document) but not inside a `div`, except for browsers not following the norm.

In your case the easiest workaround would probably be to use an `iframe`. Note that the css won't apply to the parent document.

Comment: but i don't want to use the iframe(want to load the child page using ajax into parent page) and i don't want the css present in my ajax page to apply for the parent page and page works fine when i remove the head tag alone, i.e when i place the script and link tag as siblings to div tag with id content

Answer (score 0):

Use a [documentFragment to store the responseText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404715/jquery-load-mixed-http-https-and-internet-explorer/4404752#4404752), then perform the following steps:

- Strip out the CSS that should not be applied
- Move the script tag into the body
- Remove the `head` tag
- Append the result to the parent page